# C# UWP View two database line

Tags: c#, mysql, database, uwp

```
string myConnectionString;
myConnectionString = "server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root;database=medicloud;SslMode=None;charset=utf8";

MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
string sqlStr = "Select arm from assign where userId=@name";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtValue.Text);

cmd.CommandText = sqlStr;
cmd.Connection = connection;

EncodingProvider ppp;
ppp = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

connection.Open();

MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
string databaseLine = (reader["arm"].ToString());
connection.Close();

#endregion
txtExercise.Text = databaseLine + " (Uncomplete)\n" + databaseLine;
```

I am trying to view two lines of data in the database. However, I don't know how can I view it. Can someone help me? I tried to type "databaseLine" two times but both view the same line

[image: This is my database setup]

As you can see, There two types of exercise under **Rachel**. I want to view both exercises at **txtExercise.Text**. But I only can view the first one, I am not able to view the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reader.Read()` move the reader to the next row. You only call it once, so only the first row is read.

You can do this in a while loop.

```
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) //reader.Read returns false when there are no more rows.
{
    string databaseLine = (reader["arm"].ToString()); //read the value of the current row
    txtExercise.Text += databaseLine + " (Uncomplete)\n"; //append the value to the output        
}
```